# White notification LED not working in Nougat

Tags: notifications, motorola-moto-g, 7.0-nougat, notification-led

Somehow none of my notifications seem to trigger the flashing white LED on my Moto G5 running Nougat.

On my past Android phones I remember the white LED to be a convenient way to know I had something waiting for me (e.g. a missed call or a whatsapp message) especially when my phone was placed a bit far away.

Is there some global setting I must enable for the white LED to be active?

e.g. I checked Whatsapp and its settings do show "Light->White" as enabled under notifications.

Anything else I can check?

PS. Is the White LED setting granular? i.e. Can I control which notifications trigger the white light?

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Settings-> Notifications-> Tap on `settings symbol` on top.

  Under `Lights` check whether notification light pulse is enabled or not.
- Also you can set custom notification colors,

  Goto `Notification light section`(down), Inside that, under `General` section, check whether notification light enabled or not.

  Under `Advanced` section, tap on use `custom values`, which enables a + on top-right, click on it, select WhatsApp and `enable` a custom value for notification light.
  (These settings from Nougat 7.1.2 )

Comment: Thanks! I tried  Settings-> Notifications-> Tap on settings symbol but that does not seem to have a "Lights" option at all. Does this mean the Moto G5 just does NOT have a LED light? I am wondering.

Comment: After searching, I found that Moto G5 Plus have a hidden led which can be enabled only after rooting the device, which may void warrenty.

Answer (score 1):

Moto phones since roughly last three years have done away with LED notifications and have a white LED only to show [Charging status](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-G5-Moto-G5-Plus/Notification-light/td-p/3592232)

> Same as other moto phones.  LED exists for dead phone to show charging, but not for notifications.

Also see [this for Moto G first generation](https://motorola-global-en-roe.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/97365/p/30,6720,9050/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ5ODU1OTAyOC9zaWQvek41ZVA5bW4%3D)

> Will the white noficiation LED light when charging? - Moto G 1st Generation?
>
> Not always. The white notification LED only lights when charging and the battery voltage is not enough to power the display. If you see this light, press and hold the power button for up to five minutes until your device begins charging.

Unless you root your device, it would not be possible to convert into it into LED light as on other OEM devices ( I have Moto X Play and it is possible on my device after rooting )

Comment: Even G5 plus doesn't have LED - it's a Motorola thing